# Is it possible to conditionally color databar based on background color of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Can a databar be the same color as the background color of another cell without VB code?

Actually depends on the value of the cell which is calculated average from a pivot table. If value is 0 to 4 color = Red, if value = 5 color = Yellow, if value 6 or 7 then color = Green.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Do you want to "take" the color of another cell with a formula ?

Comment: Actually depends on the value of the cell which is calculated average from a pivot table.  If value is 0 to 4 color = Red, if value = 5 color = Yellow, if value 6 or 7 then color = Green.

Comment: Have you tried to add a conditional format for each of those criteria?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get round the limit of the default settings for databars, i.e. one colour for positive values and optionally a second colour for negatives.

It's actually possible to set separate conditions manually with different-coloured databars for different value ranges. You just have to be careful with the order they appear in the list of conditions.

You might want to have a look at [an add-on I made](https://digimac.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/multicoloured-data-bars-in-excel/) a couple of years ago. It opens a form that does it all for you. And you can set a load of options for each range of values, like solid/gradient, with or without label or border.